# How to use function with Any input

Tags: scala, types

I have to define a second order function that takes as a parameter a function.

In my application, the input function may have any input type, but the output type has to be a specified one (suppose Int, it does not matter).

I define the second order function has:

```
def sof(f : (Any => Int) ) = {...}
```

Now, if I have a function `f : Int => Int`, and I call:

```
sof(f)
```

I get:

```
 found   : Int => Int
 required: Any => Int
```

I guess I am misunderstanding the meaning of the Any type.

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameters of functions in Scala are contravariant. That means that `Int => Int` is not a subtype of `Any => Int`, but vice-versa. Imagine the following: You pass a String to the `Any => Int` function (that is actually implemented by a `Int => Int` function). How would the `Int => Int` handle the String argument?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I see. Is there a way for doing what I need to do?

Comment: Depends on what the functions do. You could either change `def sof(f : (Any => Int) ) = {...}` to `def sof(f : (Int => Int) ) = {...}` or `f : Int => Int` to `f : Any => Int`.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use `Any` there, but a type parameter such as:

```
def sof[A](f: A => Int) = {...}
```

However I don't think you can do much with that method. Probably you would want something like this:

```
def sof[A](a: A)(f: A => Int) = f(a)

// usage example
val x = sof("hello")(_.size * 2) // the result is 10

// you can also partially apply it to obtain other functions
val sizeDoubler: String => Int = sof(_)(_.size * 2)

val helloDoubleSize = sizeDoubler("hello") // the result is 10
```

This way you can pass any type to `sof` plus you'll have the compiler by your side to signal any strange behaviour. Using `Any` you lose this ability.

Final Note: In case the syntax I used to pass two parameters (the `A` value and the `A => Int` function) to a method looks strange to you that's called currying. If you Google it you'll find many good articles about it.